# How to auto-start Jenkins in Ubuntu?

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-12.04, autostart

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. And i want to Jenkins to get automatically start with my system to perform building the tasks. Kindly let me know the steps

Comment: Better you can use "cron" job to start the jenkins and schedule your job/task as your wish which time you have to build using "Schedule Build Plugin".

Answer (score 3):

The best way to achieve this, in case you want to use Jenkin's built-in web server, is just to install a prepacked version of the software available at [official Jenkins Debian/Ubuntu repository](http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/). It's as easy as installing any other software on Debian/Ubuntu-like distro. The package will add a startup scripts to your installation which you can control as any other daemon.

If you preffer to use your own installation you can use a startup script that is [available on Jenkin's GitHub repository](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/debian/debian/jenkins.init). Quite possibly you will have to modify it to suite your installation, but it's a very good starting point...

Comment: `sudo apt-get install jenkins` and job done - there can't be a simpler way than this!

Comment: Depending if the package is in one of the repositories already registered in the system.

Comment: I had already installed Jenkins and doing builds successfully. i need Jenkins to start automatically when i start my system

Comment: Take the script and just modify the locations according to your installatiom. It should work fine. Put in your rc and you're done.

Comment: @ŁukaszRżanek can you please let me know the script

Comment: The script is, as previously noted, [available on Jenkin's GitHub repository](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/debian/debian/jenkins.init). Just follow [this link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/debian/debian/jenkins.init) and copy the script locally. You will, probably, introduce some changes in order to address different paths, etc.

Comment: @ŁukaszRżanek- i am unable to pick the exact script. can you please give me the exact script which needs to be added. Thanks in advance

Comment: @askannan - https://raw.github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/master/debian/debian/jenkins.init

Comment: Thanks @ŁukaszRżanek but the thing is do you need me to add all these scripts or let me know the exact scripts from this link to add and where to add. Thanks

Comment: @askannan - this is *just* a startup script. Usually it will depend on some Linux base packages like deamon, etc. - in most cases, handled automatically by your friendly Debian packaging system. If you wish not to install the Jenkins package and let you apt system worry for that, you will need to find all the dependencies by hand all modify the script accordingly. At the end of that road you will need to activate the script within you rc config.

My suggestion was and is, if you do not know how to do it by hand, to install the package with all of that already prepared for you...

Comment: Latest scripts can be found here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Unix+daemon

Answer (score 2):

Go to your `/etc/rc.local` file and add the line: `/etc/init.d/jenkins start` to your file

This will run your jenkins start command on startup.

Answer (score 1):

If jenkins is not starting at boot time install the chkconfig package:

```
apt-get install chkconfig
```

And then issue the following command:

```
chkconfig --add jenkins
```

Finally, with chkconfig --list you should obtain a list with a line inside stating the runlevels at which jenkins will start:

```
jenkins                   0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in ubuntu

update -rc.d jenkins defaults